# Handlebars didn't render HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have created an express project. I use express-handlebars as view engine but it's not work. It rendered plain text.

This is my app.js

```
app.use(morgan('combined'))
// Template engine
app.engine('handlebars', handle({
  extname: '.handlebars'
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'resources/views'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home')
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

main.handlebars

```
<body>
     
    {{body}}
    
</body>
```

home.handlebars
`<h1>Home</h1>`
and it display `<h1>Home</h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a bracket. It must be

```
{{{body}}}
```